# How to send mail using this smtp server?

Tags: email

The SMTP server is set up as this.

```
hasAuthorization: Y
username: mail@domainname.com
password: mail@password
senderEmail: sender@domainname.com
properties:
  mail.smtp.auth: true
  mail.smtp.host: mail.domainname.com
  mail.smtp.starttls.enable: true
  #mail.smtp.ssl.enable: true
  mail.smtp.ssl.protocols: TLSv1.1
  mail.smtp.port: 587
  mail.debug: true
```

Can you guide me towards, how can I send an email to myname@gmail.com using this smtp?

I am comfortable using Linux bash, Python or Perl.

ssmtp is not installed. It's a basic centos 7 machine.

I honestly don't know if this is even possible? I need to send emails to see alerts via a bash script. I hope it's possible.

```
echo "This is the message body and contains the message" | mailx -v -r "someone@example.com" -s "This is the subject" -S smtp="mail.example.com:587" -S smtp-use-starttls -S smtp-auth=login -S smtp-auth-user="someone@example.com" -S smtp-auth-password="abc123" -S ssl-verify=ignore yourfriend@gmail.com
```

I tried a variation of this command and I was getting `550 Access Denied-Invalid HELO name`

Comment: A "basic CENTOS 7 machine" will generally have some mail server installed, be it Sendmail, Postfix, or something else, because a lot of internal status messages will be passed via internal email. And your mail client (mailx) will be set to talk to that mail server. But your config doesn't look like it's correct for any of them. Is that the client config? And which server do you have installed?